# Azure App Service gives 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: azure, .net-core, service, azure-virtual-network

I am a total newcomer to the Azure cloud. I have this .net-core 2.0 app which runs locally on my development PC (Ubuntu Linux 17.10).

I have followed this guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-dotnetcore

... and I have deployed my app to the App Service container.
However, when I go to the app in my browser I get:

"503 Service Temporarily Unavailable"

Now, there are probably thousand things which can go wrong. However, I can't seem to find any debug logs/console logs to look into - so I am kinda looking with my eyes closed (It's not easy to debug that way).

It should be noted that I am on a free trial which have given me a $200 credit to use in the next 30 days.

How do one debug when a service is failing (yes, I've already tried the various suggestions on the portal but with no luck)?

Comment: I test in my lab according to this guide, I don't meet your error. Do you change something? When you execute `git push azure master`, do you get some error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do one debug when a service is failing?

You could check deployment log on Azure Portal.

[image]

Click first commit, you will see the log.

Also, you could access Kudu console to check the log. You could access `http://<webapp name>.scm.azurewebsites.net`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help!   After a bit of digging around I found the following in the docker.log:

Comment: `code`2017-12-11T15:45:27.821339257Z Error:
2017-12-11T15:45:27.821380557Z   An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest was not found:
2017-12-11T15:45:27.821399357Z     package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery', version: '2.0.1'
2017-12-11T15:45:27.821405058Z     path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'
2017-12-11T15:45:27.821410258Z   This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the application was published using the following target manifest files:
2017-12-11T15:45:27.821415558Z     aspnetcore-store-2.0.3.xml`code`

Comment: Now I just need to find a way to include the Antiforgery dll - but that is probably pretty easy to solve!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Migrating OP's self-answer from the question:

> I solved this by adding this to the PropertyGroup in my *.csproj file:
>
> ```
> <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
> ```
>
> (as per: https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/476)
>
> Now my app works and gives the expected output.